# Disabling Thief Ship in Deluxe Galaga

Tags: galaga

There's this nasty guy Thief Ship that randomly (although I really feel like he comes *every* time I have any decent amount of money) pops up and sucks all f your money.  [MonroeWorld](http://deluxegalaga.monroeworld.com/learn.php) says it can be disabled:

> There are at least three ships that seemingly appear randomly during
>   the game - the HURRY UP ship, the LAZER SHIP, and the ever-dreaded
>   THIEF SHIP (which can actually be disabled in configuration).

But how can it be done?  I haven't found anything on the site, in docs or in game configuration (both the normal in-game screen or the one you get to by holding Fire during startup).

This alien really breaks the game for me.

Answer (score 1):

The option is on the configuration screen (hold fire during startup), but it is called "Cash Sucker" there.

I checked this with the 2.6C Amiga AGA version.